# How to rename columns in a datasource for Tableau without braking the report?

Tags: database, database-connection, rename, tableau-api

I am facing the challenge of changing a column in our data warehouse which affects one tableau data source which then affects multiple reports.
If I rename the column, the report itself claims that this column does not exist any more an spits out an error. Having multiple reports attached to this datasource would imply that I need to open up all the reports and change them manually.

```
+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+----------+
| column 1 | column 2 | change -> | column renamed | column 2 |
+----------+----------+           +----------------+----------+
| data 1   | data 1   |           | data 1         | data 1   |
+----------+----------+           +----------------+----------+
| data 2   | data 2   |           | data 2         | data 2   |
+----------+----------+           +----------------+----------+
| data 3   | data 3   |           | data 3         | data 3   |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+----------+
```

Is there a smart way of doing a column rename without changing all the reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename a column in your database where tableau is running an extract on (and uses it for reporting) - there is no "tableau" way without fixing all the reports (and its elements) manually.

The only way I found so far is editing the workbook file directly. Tableau stores its workbooks in either *twb* or *twbx* files.
You can open these files (which are nothing else than XML files) directly in any editor of your choice like sublime / Atom / notepad.
Within these file you can find the columns which you want to rename in the DB. In the example I want to rename *Column1* to *column renamed*.

[image: Find the columns here]

Like in a normal texteditor just go for search&replace and replace all occurences of *Column1* to *column renamed*.

[image: Rename it in all occurences]

The last step is to safe it (you should use a different filename to test if it works first) and open it in tableau.
Without any big hustle you adapted your tableau workbook to all the renamed columns.

Comment: If you do manually edit Tableau workbooks and rename a field, you can right-click on the old field in the data pane in the sidebar and choose the "replace references" command -- a global search and replace command.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Alex Blakemore in a comment to the answer,

"If you do manually edit Tableau workbooks and rename a field, you can right-click on the old field in the data pane in the sidebar and choose the "replace references" command -- a global search and replace command." – Alex Blakemore Aug 22 '17 at 16:41

Verified by myself that it works.